# Laravel - copy image

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i need to copy an image and save in diferent name. how can i do this in laravel?

Please help me.

```
img/master.jpg -> copy -> paste with different name (user1)
----now------
img/master.jpg
img/user1.jpg
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use laravel `File` helper, here is the [file System Doc](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html).

```
$oldPath = 'images/1.jpg'; // publc/images/1.jpg
$newPath = 'images/2.jpg'; // publc/images/2.jpg

if (\File::copy($oldPath , $newPath)) {
    dd("success");
}
```

---

if you need to rename it following would be helpful,

```
$oldPath = 'images/1.jpg'; // publc/images/1.jpg

$fileExtension = \File::extension($oldPath);
$newName = 'new file.'.$fileExtension;
$newPathWithName = 'images/'.$newName;

if (\File::copy($oldPath , $newPathWithName)) {
    dd("success");
}
```

Comment: after that can i access both files? or only images/2.jpg ?

Comment: you can access both because we get the copy, if you need to move the file instead of a copy then you can use `\File::move($oldPath , $newPath)`

Comment: Thanks, do I have to install File helper or is it coming default with laravel 4.2

Comment: its coming with laravel. :)

Comment: i am getting error fail to open stream: no shuch a file or directry

Comment: $oldPath = 'uploads/kite.jpg'; 
$newPath = 'uploads/'.$user->username.'.jpg'; 

    if (File::copy($oldPath , $newPath)) {
        dd("success");
    }

Comment: `$oldPath = 'images/1.jpg';` then `1.jpg` image should be in `images` fo;der under `public` directory.

Comment: so then your `kite.jpg` file should be in `uploads` directory under `public` directory. check the extension is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73574/discussion-between-kombuwa-and-k-toress).

Comment: that's great. glad to help u :)